# undefined reference to functions in ncurses library

Tags: c, linux, gcc, ncurses

I was trying to compile following code using ncurses library v 5.9. on Debian wheezy.
But i am getting undefined refernce to the library fucntions.
I installed the library from sources.

```
#include <curses.h>
#include <menu.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define ARRAY_SIZE(a) (sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]))
#define CTRLD   4

char *choices[] = {
                    "Choice 1",
                    "Choice 2",
                    "Choice 3",
                    "Choice 4",
                    "Exit",
              };

int main()
{   ITEM **my_items;
int c;              
MENU *my_menu;
int n_choices, i;
ITEM *cur_item;


initscr();
cbreak();
noecho();
keypad(stdscr, TRUE);

n_choices = ARRAY_SIZE(choices);
my_items = (ITEM **)calloc(n_choices + 1, sizeof(ITEM *));

for(i = 0; i < n_choices; ++i)
        my_items[i] = new_item(choices[i], choices[i]);
my_items[n_choices] = (ITEM *)NULL;

my_menu = new_menu((ITEM **)my_items);
mvprintw(LINES - 2, 0, "F1 to Exit");
post_menu(my_menu);
refresh();

while((c = getch()) != KEY_F(1))
{   switch(c)
    {   case KEY_DOWN:
            menu_driver(my_menu, REQ_DOWN_ITEM);
            break;
        case KEY_UP:
            menu_driver(my_menu, REQ_UP_ITEM);
            break;
    }
}   

free_item(my_items[0]);
free_item(my_items[1]);
free_menu(my_menu);
endwin();   
}
```

Here is the error

```
root@sss:/home/sss/Desktop# gcc -Wall -o mn mn.c -lncurses -lmenu
mn.c: In function ‘main’:
mn.c:21:8: warning: unused variable ‘cur_item’ [-Wunused-variable]
mn.c:58:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../../lib/libmenu.a(m_driver.o): In function `menu_driver':
m_driver.c:(.text+0x33b): undefined reference to `getmouse'
m_driver.c:(.text+0x36c): undefined reference to `wenclose'
m_driver.c:(.text+0x3b0): undefined reference to `wmouse_trafo'
m_driver.c:(.text+0x7b9): undefined reference to `wenclose'
m_driver.c:(.text+0x7f2): undefined reference to `wmouse_trafo'
/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../../lib/libmenu.a(m_global.o): In function `_nc_Show_Menu':
m_global.c:(.text+0x78b): undefined reference to `copywin'
/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../../lib/libmenu.a(m_post.o): In function `_nc_Post_Item':
m_post.c:(.text+0x3c): undefined reference to `wattr_on'
m_post.c:(.text+0x8e): undefined reference to `wattr_off'
m_post.c:(.text+0xce): undefined reference to `wattr_on'
m_post.c:(.text+0x276): undefined reference to `wattr_on'
m_post.c:(.text+0x3a3): undefined reference to `wattr_off'
m_post.c:(.text+0x3db): undefined reference to `wattr_off'
m_post.c:(.text+0x424): undefined reference to `wattr_on'
m_post.c:(.text+0x458): undefined reference to `wattr_on'
m_post.c:(.text+0x47e): undefined reference to `wattr_on'
m_post.c:(.text+0x4ce): undefined reference to `wattr_on'
m_post.c:(.text+0x4fe): undefined reference to `wattr_off'
m_post.c:(.text+0x51e): undefined reference to `wattr_off'
m_post.c:(.text+0x53a): undefined reference to `wattr_off'
m_post.c:(.text+0x5b6): undefined reference to `wattr_off'
/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../../lib/libmenu.a(m_post.o): In function `_nc_Draw_Menu':
m_post.c:(.text+0x605): undefined reference to `wbkgdset'
m_post.c:(.text+0x61f): undefined reference to `wbkgdset'
m_post.c:(.text+0x69e): undefined reference to `wattr_on'
m_post.c:(.text+0x774): undefined reference to `wattr_off'
/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../../lib/libmenu.a(m_post.o): In function `unpost_menu':
m_post.c:(.text+0xa41): undefined reference to `delwin'
m_post.c:(.text+0xa53): undefined reference to `delwin'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Do you get this even with the `stdlib` as the first `include` line?

Comment: Actually stdlib is not the problem. I removed it but still i get the same error

Comment: "I installed the library from sources." — why?

Comment: I executed a simple program without the menu.h header using curses.h only. It worked. No error.But when i try to use menu.h this error pops up

Comment: What i want to say is i followed the commands 1../configure 2.make 3.make install

Comment: This doesn't look like C++, not the code nor the error messages.

Answer (score 8):

Quoted directly from `man menu`:

> In your library list, libmenu.a should be before libncurses.a; that is, you want to say `-lmenu -lncurses`,  not  the  other  way  around (which would usually give a link-error).